# Change Keyboard input language

Tags: android

I am developing one android app in two different languages. When user click on "Change language" button it ask to choose language from two different languages option and change keyboard according to that language.

For example : User choose "Arabic" language then keyboard input language should automatically change from English to Arabic.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: you got the solution for the above requirement. I have the same requirement so can you please help me.

Comment: Yes , Subhalaxmi Nayak, I got the solution for this.

Comment: Are you using value folder with language code or any other solution??

Comment: I got some code to change the keyboard language programmatically.

Comment: Great .. i need your help. can you plz suggest me ..

Comment: exactly i hv same requirement and i am not getting any point to start it in effective way. For current time being I am doing as http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-building-multi-language-supported-app/ . M i in right track ?? How i can change the keypad language with different language?

Comment: Hello Subhalaxmi, you can change the keyboard directly from keyboard instead of going to setting native application.

Comment: is it.. actually i am not sure abt this before. thank you i ll try it .

Comment: Yes Its possible, and best of luck Subhalaxmi :)

Answer (score 9):

This isn't really that possible. You can change the users locale using a number of solutions present on stackoverflow already:

[Here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701882/android-change-language-programmatically), or [here for another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android).

However, this will only change the locale. The problem you will encounter is that the keyboard is itself an application. Therefore, you cannot change it directly from your app, nor can you guarantee that your user will have the "Arabic" charset or addon or whatever, for they keyboard app that they employ.

Your only real and reliable solution if you wish to accomplish what you need would be to create your own keyboard input. Otherwise, it will be in the user's hands to change their keyboard to Arabic.

Comment: Just adding that this is reinforced by custom keyboards: They always force you to change the input type yourself, though they do present you with the dialog that does this. (And keyboard languages count as an input type.)

Comment: @Eric, Can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: When you install a custom keyboard, most of them have a little setup procedure. First, you have to enable the keyboard in the settings, so the app will open that settings screen for you. Next, you have to switch input modes, so the app will open the input mode screen. If you want to try it, download TouchPal keyboard (it's free), and go through the setup procedure. You'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 6):

(API 24+): If you are using a `TextView`/`EditText`, then you can call [TextView#setImeHintLocales(LocaleList)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setImeHintLocales(android.os.LocaleList))

```java
textView.setImeHintLocales(new LocaleList(new Locale("zh", "CN")));
```

**Note:** If you want new "hint" to take effect immediately you need to call `InputMethodManager#restartInput(View)`.

Comment: This works, you save my day