# How to access urdu keyboard in android app

Tags: android

I am just making a signature maker application in which I want to use an Urdu keyboard, but I can, t access it. how can I do this can anyone help me please.

Comment: can you provide more info. Your question is not precise

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12303593/5028508

Comment: i want to show urdu text alphabet in edit text when i click on urdu keyboard .how can i do this

Comment: can you help me .give me some guidness #PedroAGSantos