# In android, how can I change IME from my app to use gboard instead of the native keyboard from the device manufacturer

Tags: android, xamarin, keyboard, ime, gboard

I am looking for a way to programmatically detect if gboard (google's keyboard) is installed on the android device and use it as the default input method for my app.

Comment: Will the application be running on rooted device? Can you try checking these links... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036435/switch-keyboard-profile-programmatically and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38122702/android-change-keyboard-programmatically

Comment: @Soumya, Thank for pointing out the post.  It is very close to what I'm looking for.  I like to be able to detect if gboard is installed and load it programmatically or notify user that gboard is recommend for use with the app.  The solution to that post was to trigger the keyboard selection option, which is not quite what I'm looking form.

Comment: @Soumya,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38122702/android-change-keyboard-programmatically is the anwer, however I need a solution that doesn't involve rooted device. :(

Comment: I think it is not possible on non-rooted devices due to security concerns. The most we can do is prompt and allow the user to choose to Gkeyboard.