# How to change the language if the keyboard in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, keyboard

in my flutter app I need to change the language of the keyboard. eg: I need to change the language of the keyboard from english to Chinese or Hindi for input. How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't. The onscreen keyboard on Android for example is controlled by the user, system & keyboard app itself. The best you can do theoretically is to provide a hint to the system about the input language of the current input element but the user's keyboard app is free to ignore that hint and show whatever language it thinks is best, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62250268/995891