# How to open keyboard and change input language

Tags: java, android

How to:
 - open keyboard without focus on edittext, 
 - check which languages are installed and
 - change input language to other language?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if the changing keyboard language is possible, you can change the entire locale with something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18733302/2864464).

Comment: Already asked before and is not possible - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303593/change-keyboard-input-language

Answer (score -2):

It's possible. You can set the locale. However, i would not recommend that. We've tried it at early stages, it's basically fighting the system. We have same requirement for changing language, but decided to settle to the fact that UI should be same as phone UI. It was working via setting locale but was too buggy. And you have to set it every time you enter activity ( each activity ) from my experience. here is a code if you still need this ( again, i don't recommend that )

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
// Change locale settings in the app.
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
conf.locale = new Locale(language_code.toLowerCase());
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

If you have language specific content - you can change that base on the setting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2900144/3348373 Copy Paste! Give some credits to original author

Comment: down voted it he took it copy and paste from the original auther without referring to him http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303593/change-keyboard-input-language